# My app only has a broadcast receiver. Will it work on all versions of android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have developed an app which only has a `BroadcastReceiver` (no `Activity` + no `Service`) - its for a specific purpose.

I was able to test my app on v2.3.3 and it works perfectly well. Will it work the same on all platforms or there are exceptions to this? If there are - what could be alternative(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will not work on all versions.

[Starting Android 3.1](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols) (API 12), you cannot receive broadcasts until a UI component of your app (an Activity) has been manually opened by the user at least once.

Comment: Thank you for the link (I was looking for it but couldn't locate). What are your views on this: "A background service or application can override this behavior by adding the FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES flag to broadcast intents that should be allowed to activate stopped applications."?

Comment: @Mahendra That means that when an app sends a broadcast, it can include that flag to make all apps receive it. However, you cannot make other apps add it